# How do I merge a folder of PNG images to a mp4 movie using avconv?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, png, libav

I have a folder containing many time stamped PNG images which I'd like to merge to a short movie. The contents of that directory looks like this:

```
└── images
    ├── img_20130421_115547.png
    ├── img_20130421_115617.png
    ├── img_20130421_115926.png
    ├── img_20130421_120034.png
    ├── img_20130421_120129.png
    ├── img_20130421_120245.png
    ├── img_20130421_120354.png
    ├── ...
```

I tried running the following commands inside the images directory, to no avail:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i 'img*.png' -r 24 out.mp4
ffmpeg version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Apr  2 2013 17:02:16 with gcc 4.7.2
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
Unrecognized option 'pattern_type'
Failed to set value 'glob' for option 'pattern_type'

$ avconv -y -f image2 -r 24 -i 'img_%08d_%06d.png' out.mp4
avconv version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Apr  2 2013 17:02:16 with gcc 4.7.2
img_%08d_%06d.png: No such file or directory

$ avconv -y -f image2 -r 24 -i 'img_%*.png' out.mp4     
avconv version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Apr  2 2013 17:02:16 with gcc 4.7.2
img_%*.png: No such file or directory

$ avconv -y -f image2 -r 24 -i 'img_%.png' out.mp4 
avconv version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Apr  2 2013 17:02:16 with gcc 4.7.2
img_%.png: No such file or directory
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10. How do I get this to work? thanks.

Comment: Get a more recent version of `ffmpeg` from [the actual FFmpeg project](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), not the ill-named and outdated `ffmpeg` that comes with Ubuntu, which is from [Libav](http://libav.org/), the FFmpeg fork.

Answer (score 4):

## Use `ffmpeg`, not `avconv`

`avconv` does not support the "glob pattern" (among many other things). Use `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg instead (not the old, fake "`ffmpeg`" from the Libav fork).

See the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to already compiled binaries for Linux, OS X, and Windows. Or follow a [compile guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).

### Example

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -pattern_type glob -i "*.png" output.mkv
```

- Consider adding the output option `-vf format=yuv420p` (or the alias `-pix_fmt yuv420p`) when outputting H.264 video from images so the output is compatible with QuickTime, WMP, and other dumb players.
- See the [FFmpeg image file demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) for more info.

Comment: Read the question. He asks specifically for **avconv**

Comment: @Ronny-AndréBendiksen Read the answer. It is not possible with `avconv` alone. The OP's command was using `ffmpeg` options that are not supported by `avconv`. Secondly, this question was asked more than 4 years ago–was your comment necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Use the image2pipe demuxer. `cat *png | avconv -f image2pipe -i - ....`